# tkinter button image not loading (toplevel)

Tags: python-3.x, image, user-interface, tkinter, toplevel

I am working with a resized image in a button and that button is in a toplevel widget set up as a root widget. The problem is that the image will not load; code:

```
def opendl():
global installpin2
# dl = install
root.destroy()
dlwin = Tk()
#functions
def openinstall():
    os.startfile('E:\bigdirectory\PROGRAMS\shortcut.lnk')
#images
dlwin.title("subwindow title")
dlwin.resizable(False, False)
installpin = Image.open('E:\bigdirectory\GUI\img\Folder catalog.ico')
installpinr = installpin.resize((181, 185), Image.ANTIALIAS)
installpin2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(installpinr)
#code
dlcanvas = Canvas(dlwin, height=500, width=1500)
dlframe = Frame(dlwin, bg='#3D3E40') # R61,G62,B64
dlframe.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
label = Label(dlframe, text="biglabel", font=("vga932", 35), bg='#3D3E40', fg='white')
label.place(height=230, relwidth=1)
line = Canvas(dlframe, bg='white')
line.place(height=3, width=900, relx=.20, y=145)
buttoncon = Frame(dlframe, bg='#3D3E40', highlightthickness=0, relief='flat', width=1500)
labelbcon = Label(buttoncon, text="Install Program", font=(default), bg='#3D3E40', fg='white')
labelbcon.place(relx=.3, y=220)
but = Button(buttoncon, command=openinstall, image=installpin2, bg='#3D3E40', fg='#3D3E40', relief='flat', cursor='plus')
but.place(relx=.285, y=38)
buttoncon.place(y=150)
dlcanvas.pack()
dlwin.mainloop
```

I am not sure why this is happening and the label located above the button in the code is also not showing up so please help if you can and thank you-kik

Comment: you didn't place the buttoncon Frame so you can't see anything inside

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. You can't use `but.place`
from tkinter import *

```
def opendl():
    global installpin2
    
# dl = install
root.destroy()
dlwin = Tk()
#functions
def openinstall():
    os.startfile('E:\bigdirectory\PROGRAMS\shortcut.lnk')
#images
dlwin.title("subwindow title")
dlwin.resizable(False, False)
installpin = Image.open('E:\bigdirectory\GUI\img\Folder catalog.ico')
installpinr = installpin.resize((181, 185), Image.ANTIALIAS)
installpin2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(installpinr)
#code
dlcanvas = Canvas(dlwin, height=500, width=1500)
dlframe = Frame(dlwin, bg='#3D3E40') # R61,G62,B64
dlframe.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
label = Label(dlframe, text="biglabel", font=("vga932", 35), bg='#3D3E40', fg='white')
label.place(height=230, relwidth=1)
line = Canvas(dlframe, bg='white')
line.place(height=3, width=900, relx=.20, y=145)
buttoncon = Frame(dlframe, bg='#3D3E40', highlightthickness=0, relief='flat', width=1500)
labelbcon = Label(buttoncon, text="Install Program", font=(default), bg='#3D3E40', fg='white')
labelbcon.place(relx=.3, y=220)
but = Button(buttoncon, command=openinstall, image=installpin2, bg='#3D3E40', fg='#3D3E40', relief='flat', cursor='plus')
but.config(height = 2, width = 15)
but.grid(padx=25, pady=25,sticky = S)
buttoncon.place(y=150)
dlcanvas.pack()
dlwin.mainloop
```

Ouput:
[image]

Btw, I did not add icon on title. You may have to fix for **newnbie**.

As you can see `buttoncon.place` So I Add x axis and object I change but = `Button(dlframe` not buttoncon. You will have to fix x and y.
from tkinter import *

```
def opendl():
    global installpin2
    
# dl = install
root.destroy()
dlwin = Tk()
#functions
def openinstall():
    os.startfile('E:\bigdirectory\PROGRAMS\shortcut.lnk')
#images
dlwin.title("subwindow title")
dlwin.resizable(False, False)
installpin = Image.open('E:\bigdirectory\GUI\img\Folder catalog.ico')
installpinr = installpin.resize((181, 185), Image.ANTIALIAS)
installpin2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(installpinr)
#code
dlcanvas = Canvas(dlwin, height=500, width=1500)
dlframe = Frame(dlwin, bg='#3D3E40') # R61,G62,B64
dlframe.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
label = Label(dlframe, text="biglabel", font=("vga932", 35), bg='#3D3E40', fg='white')
label.place(height=230, relwidth=1)
line = Canvas(dlframe, bg='white')
line.place(height=3, width=900, relx=.20, y=145)
buttoncon = Frame(dlframe, bg='#3D3E40', highlightthickness=0, relief='flat', width=1500)
labelbcon = Label(buttoncon, text="Install Program", font=(default), bg='#3D3E40', fg='white')
labelbcon.place(relx=.3, y=220)
but = Button(dlframe,, command=openinstall, image=installpin2, bg='#3D3E40', fg='#3D3E40', relief='flat', cursor='plus')
but.config(height = 2, width = 15)
but.grid(padx=25, pady=25,sticky = S)
#buttoncon.config(height = 2, width = 55) 
buttoncon.place(x=5, y=10)
dlcanvas.pack()
dlwin.mainloop
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You will see red buttncon on top. I changed my  color to see it.